# Does Win 2008 R2 still have 32 bit edition?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I was looking for the proper version of Win 2008 R2 to download, and cannot find a 32 bit.  Is it 64-bit only?  I'm still on a 32-bit machine, going to run it under VMWare.  Do I need to go back to the original Win 2008 (i.e. the one before R2)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of Server 2008 R2, Microsoft is no longer shipping 32-bit versions of their Server operating systems. Yes, this does indeed put a maximum version limit on 32-bit only hardware! We can't upgrade our Domain Controllers to R2 because of this, we need new hardware for it. Those old Pentium 4's won't handle 64-bit.

Comment: There's a lot of software starting at the end of last year that is 64-bit only. Notably: Exchange 2007, the Dynamics line, ForeFront (Server services only), and many require 64-bit SQL Server. For the most part, only the home products are still actively developing 32-bit versions, and that is likely to end in the next year or two (I'd speculate Office will have one more version that's 32-bit, but Windows will not).

Comment: Those bastards! Expecting you to deploy a new server OS on hardware that is less than seven years old!